# Can we upload images to cpanel using multer and node?

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, multer

I am using multer with express to upload images to the server, i want to deploy my node js app to cpanel but i don't know if multer works there or not?
Does Node has access to fs in cpanel?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, cPanel Create A Environment to Run Node.js App

where you can excute any type of program on that environment

Environment is built with python package library `pip install nodeenv`
i did reverse eng.. in cPanel

And Yes You can also store image there